# is there any way by which we can send email to the registered user

Tags: javascript, reactjs, email, react-redux, react-hooks

i am developing registration page in my react app.what i want to do is to email confirmation email to the users email id when he registers on the app.And his account gets confirmed when he clicks on that link.is there any library in the reactjs which can help in this matters.i dont want to do this with backend .want to do in my react app

Comment: See [how to send email in nodeJS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YU3qstG74nw)

Answer (score 1):

You can use emailJs for this purpose

Answer (score 0):

This Blog can help you  [Link](https://mailtrap.io/blog/react-send-email/)

But best solution will be to use backend for this, since you will call backend routes for registering users, You can send mail there as well , You can use [NodeMailer](https://nodemailer.com/about/) as well.